# Singly-linked queue in PHP 7

Tags: php, object-oriented, linked-list, queue

I am learning PHP 7 and decided to implement a simple FIFO singly-linked queue in it:

```
<?php

class QueueNode {
    var $item;
    var $next;

    function __construct($item) {
        $this->item = $item;
    }

    function get_item() {
        return $this->item;
    }
}

class Queue {
    var $head;
    var $tail;
    var $size;

    function push($item) {
        if ($this->size == 0) {
            $this->head = $this->tail = new QueueNode($item);
        } else {
            $new_node = new QueueNode($item);
            $this->tail->next = $new_node;
            $this->tail = $new_node;
        }

        $this->size++;
    }

    function pop() {
        if ($this->size == 0) {
            throw new Exception("Popping from an empty queue.");
        }

        $ret = $this->head->item;
        $this->head = $this->head->next;

        if (--$this->size == 0) {
            $this->head = $this->tail = null;
        }

        return $ret;
    }
}

$queue = new Queue();

for ($i = 1; $i <= 10; $i++) {
    $queue->push($i);
}

for ($i = 1; $i <= 10; $i++) {
    echo $queue->pop() . " ";
}

echo "<br>";
?>
```

As always, any critique is much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Getters and setters

So there is a getter for item (i.e. `get_item()`) - why not a getter (and setter) for the `next` property? If getters and setters are added, then those properties could be set to `private` visibility if deemed appropriate.

Are you familiar with the [PHP Standards Recommendations](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/)? While it is only a suggestion, you might find them helpful for writing code that is maintainable and readable, not only for others but also your future self.

According to [PSR-1](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-1/):

> Method names MUST be declared in `camelCase()`.<sup>[1](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-1/#43-methods)</sup>

A format of `getItem()` is more widely used amongst many PHP developers.

#### Types and conditions

Inside `Queue::push()` and `Queue::pop()` I see this common first line:

> ```
> if ($this->size == 0) {
> ```

It is advisable to use strict equality comparison operators (i.e. `===` and `!==`) to avoid excess type-juggling. As a consequence, `size` should perhaps be declared with a initial value of `0`.

The conditional could also be shortened to `if (!$this->size) {` though that would allow any type that is considered to **`FALSE`** to allow the conditional block to be executed.

#### keyword `var`

`var` is a feature from PHP 4 and it isn't needed anymore<sup>[2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1206120/1575353)</sup> - while it works as a synonym for `public` it is deprecated. If you adhere to [PSR-2](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-2/) then note it specifies:

> The `var` keyword MUST NOT be used to declare a property.<sup>[3](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-2/#42-properties)</sup>

#### `for` loops

There isn't anything wrong with a traditional loop, but you could use the [`range()`](https://php.net/range) function to iterate `$i` for you in a `foreach` loop:

> ```
> for ($i = 1; $i <= 10; $i++) {
> ```

can be changed to:

```
foreach(range(1, 10) as $i) {
```